# SQL Where Clause Logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains an id field along with 5 fields, one for each week-day from Monday to Friday, where datatype is bit.

The table looks something like:

```
+---+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|id | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
+---+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 1 |      1 |       0 |         0 |        0 |      0 |
+---+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 2 |      1 |       0 |         0 |        0 |      0 |
+---+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 3 |      0 |       0 |         0 |        1 |      0 |
+---+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 4 |      1 |       0 |         0 |        0 |      1 |
+---+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Depending on the day I'm trying to return the rows that have the bit set to true for that day.  I was thinking of doing this with a where clause but can't get it to work.

I think there is something wrong in my logic, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
DECLARE @tDay as INTEGER
SET @tDay = datepart(weekday, getdate())

SELECT     id, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday
FROM         Days
WHERE   CASE WHEN @tDay = 2 then @tDay 
        Else Days.monday
        End = 1
        AND 
        CASE WHEN @tDay = 3 then @tDay 
        Else Days.tuesday
        End = 1
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and a sample output that you desire?

Comment: 1 True False True False True 2 True True True False True  if it's monday I only want the rows with True for the first column returned, thanks!

Comment: You could edit the post directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work if [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) is 7. You need to adjust if you have some other day as first day of the week.

```
DECLARE @tDay as INTEGER
SET @tDay = datepart(weekday, getdate())

select id, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday
from Days
where case @tDay
        when 2 then monday
        when 3 then tuesday
        when 4 then wednesday
        when 5 then thursday
        when 6 then friday
      end = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT     id, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday
FROM         Days
WHERE
        CASE @tDay
          WHEN 2 THEN monday
          WHEN 3 THEN tuesday 
          WHEN 4 THEN wednesday
          WHEN 5 THEN thursday
          WHEN 6 THEN friday
          ELSE NULL
        END  = 1
```